Problem with fetching PDA data in frontend
I am having a problem with fetching PDA data in frontend.
Error: Invalid account discriminator
    at Nt.decode (index.js:1403:70)
    at En.fetchNullable (index.js:3182:57)
    at async createLoan (createLoan.ts:63:18)
    at async onSubmit (RequestLoanForm.tsx:78:17)
    at async eval (index.esm.mjs:2119:21)

Code:
const [loanPda] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("prefix_loan_seed"), payer.toBuffer()],
      program.programId
    );
const loan = await program.account.loanPda.fetch(loanPda);

Basically, above code works while running tests in anchor, but doesn't in frontend.
Idl files are exactly the same.
If I try to fetch another PDA which is not using AnchorSerialize (just with simple data), it works.
If I try using .all() instead of .fetch(loanPda), I am getting an empty array.
Initialization:
 #[account(
        init,
        space = 8 +LoanPda::INIT_SPACE,
        payer = payer,
        seeds = [b"prefix_loan_seed",payer.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    loan: Account<'info,LoanPda>,

Structs:

#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone,Copy,InitSpace,PartialEq)]
pub enum LoanState {
    Acitve,
    Pending,
    Closed,
}

#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Clone,Copy,InitSpace)]
pub struct Loan {
    pub loan_id: u32,
    pub nft_id: u32,
    pub req_amount: u64,
    pub interest: u64,
    pub period: i64,
    pub paid_amount: u64,
    pub lender: Pubkey,
    pub borrower: Pubkey,
    pub state: LoanState,
}   

#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)] 
pub struct LoanPda {
    pub bump: u8,
    pub loans: [Option<Loan>; 10],
    pub space:u32,
    pub loan_count: u8

}

I am using anchor 0.29.0
I really need fast help with that! Thanks!

Maybe your app points to devnet and there is already some other data written at that address? Does it work if you change the seed to smth else?

@JonasH. I have tried changing the seed but still having same problem

So, I have changed when I called initialize instruction and it works!,
from:
 useEffect(() => {
   if (anchorWallet) init();
 }, [anchorWallet]);

to:
 useEffect(() => {
    if (connected && anchorWallet) init();
  }, [connected]);

connected is from useWallet hook, anchorWallet is from  useAnchorWallet. I still don't know why it was initializing PDA with smaller amount of data, but not loanPda, but it works!

Maybe your wallet wasnt loaded yet and it used null as a seed for the pda in the client

@JonasH. Maybe, but still pretty weird behaviour
